# display Current date inside HTML text

Tags: html, excel, vba

I need a help with HTML code.
Basically I am writing a code in VBA to send email from excel. For each of this email sent, I need to write a message body for which I used the HTML code. The issue is i need to insert today's date inside this HTML code. 
So basically it should be like " The report is generated for 28 Aug 2017.

This is where I need help.

I have used the replace function but that too is not working.

So here's a sample of my code:

```
Dim strbody As String
Dim Rstrbody As String

strbody = "<html><body><font size = ""3"", face = ""Calibri"">Hi All<br>The report is generated for dd mmm yyyy</font></body></html>"

Rstrbody = Replace(strbody, "dd mmm yyyy", Format(Date, "dd mmm yyyy"))
```

Need help in this.Let me know if this can be done in HTML , I have no knowledge of Javascript and so wont be able to use.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the code you are writing is VBA, it seems best to keep doing in VBA, like this for example

```
Dim strBody As String
Dim strDate As String

strDate = Format(Date, "dd mmm yyyy")

strBody = "<html><body><font size = ""3"", face = ""Calibri"">Hi All<br>The report is generated for " & strDate & "</font></body></html>"
```

HTML cannot execute code to generate a date at the moment of it's use.

Your solution should word too, be sure to use `Rstrbody` as variable in the mails sent.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim strbody As String

strbody = "<html><body><font size = ""3"", face = ""Calibri"">Hi All<br>The report is generated for " & Format(Date.Today, "dd MMM yyyy") & "</font></body></html>"
```